# Split comma separated column data into additional columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, delimiter, postgresql-8.4

I have comma separated data in a column:

```
Column 
------- 
a,b,c,d
```

I want to split the comma separated data into multiple columns to get this output:

```
Column1  Column2 Column3 Column4 
-------  ------- ------- -------
a        b       c       d
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If the number of fields in the CSV is constant then you could do something like this:

```
select a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]
from (
    select regexp_split_to_array('a,b,c,d', ',')
) as dt(a)
```

For example:

```
=> select a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4] from (select regexp_split_to_array('a,b,c,d', ',')) as dt(a);
 a | a | a | a 
---+---+---+---
 a | b | c | d
(1 row)
```

If the number of fields in the CSV is not constant then you could get the maximum number of fields with something like this:

```
select max(array_length(regexp_split_to_array(csv, ','), 1))
from your_table
```

and then build the appropriate `a[1], a[2], ..., a[M]` column list for your query. So if the above gave you a max of 6, you'd use this:

```
select a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6]
from (
    select regexp_split_to_array(csv, ',')
    from your_table
) as dt(a)
```

You could combine those two queries into a function if you wanted.

For example, give this data (that's a NULL in the last row):

```
=> select * from csvs;
     csv     
-------------
 1,2,3
 1,2,3,4
 1,2,3,4,5,6

(4 rows)

=> select max(array_length(regexp_split_to_array(csv, ','), 1)) from csvs;
 max 
-----
   6
(1 row)

=> select a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6] from (select regexp_split_to_array(csv, ',') from csvs) as dt(a);
 a | a | a | a | a | a 
---+---+---+---+---+---
 1 | 2 | 3 |   |   | 
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |   | 
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
   |   |   |   |   | 
(4 rows)
```

Since your delimiter is a simple fixed string, you could also use [`string_to_array`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) instead of `regexp_split_to_array`:

```
select ...
from (
    select string_to_array(csv, ',')
    from csvs
) as dt(a);
```

Thanks to [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050226/michael) for the reminder about this function.

You really should redesign your database schema to avoid the CSV column if at all possible. You should be using an array column or a separate table instead.

Comment: Thanks shall check and revert

Comment: Consider using `string_to_array` instead of `regexp_split_to_array`; it should be faster since it doesn't have the overhead of regular expression processing.

Comment: @Michael You could add that as another answer if you'd like. Or I could add `string_to_array` as an option in mine, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Just had to run a big load of the US census. string_to_array was about faster by the factor 10.

Comment: @DennisBauszus: Nice. Did you check `split_part` too? Just curious.

Comment: Smashing. Faster by factor 3 over string_to_array. Should be marked as the answer. Note to myself: Must read all the answers.

Comment: @DennisBauszus Wouldn't argue with that. It is usually a good idea to look for what Erwin Brandsetter or Craig Ringer have to say on PostgreSQL questions, they really know their stuff and their answers tend to be quite thorough.

Answer (score 152):

[**`split_part()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) does what you want in one step:

```
SELECT split_part(col, ',', 1) AS col1
     , split_part(col, ',', 2) AS col2
     , split_part(col, ',', 3) AS col3
     , split_part(col, ',', 4) AS col4
FROM   tbl;
```

Add as many lines as you have items in `col` (the possible maximum).
Columns exceeding data items will be empty strings (`''`).

Comment: And would appear to execute a lot faster than the regexp_split_to_array version.

Comment: @JohnBarça: All regular expression function are comparatively expensive. Powerful, but for a price ...

Comment: Legend! This is by far the fastest approach to this kind of issue.

Comment: mu's answer is one step as well if the number of values is known such as this answer assumes. Michael's addition of `string_to_array` nullifies the regexp expense.

Comment: @juanitogan: True, `string_to_array` nullifies the regexp expense. But for a hand full of values, this is much faster, still. See the [comment with feedback above.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#comment59725575_8585472)

Answer (score -2):

You can use split function.

```
    SELECT 
    (select top 1 item from dbo.Split(FullName,',') where id=1 ) Column1,
    (select top 1 item from dbo.Split(FullName,',') where id=2 ) Column2,
    (select top 1 item from dbo.Split(FullName,',') where id=3 ) Column3,
    (select top 1 item from dbo.Split(FullName,',') where id=4 ) Column4,
    FROM MyTbl
```

Comment: The question refers to PostgreSQL - that's SQL Server syntax?