# Why 'A' > 'a' is true in one of my Posgresql databases?

Tags: postgresql

In one of my PostgreSQL databases, the following statement returns true! The other works fine.

`select 'A'>'a'`

`LC_COLLATE` and `LC_TYPE` in all of my databases is `en_US.UTF-8`.
`client_encoding` is `UTF8`

My database version is 13.2. OS is Linux.

In Unicode order, 'A' shall be smaller than 'a', but it isn't. Any configuration I shall look at?

Is it OS dependent? The other database that works correctly is running on MacOS.

--

`select key from json_each('{"A":1, "a":2}') order by key` => `a` and then `A`!

More weird:
`select key from json_each('{"A":1, "a":2, ":": 3, ":a": 4}') order by key`
=> `:`, `a`, `:a` and then `A`

--

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/87027) the same weird behavior, but [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0) is correct (but its collation is `C`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alphanumeric case in-sensitive sorting in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427529/alphanumeric-case-in-sensitive-sorting-in-postgres)

Comment: No, the question you pointed to is about how to do case sensitive and insensitive. But, my question is that my installation seems violate the basic string comparison rule!

Comment: Returns false here. BTW, what does `select 'B'>'a'` give you?

Comment: What does `show LC_CTYPE` display?

Comment: `select 'B'>'a'` is true too:(

`LC_TYPE` is `en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: What about `show client_encoding`?

Answer (score 1):

The character *type*, defined by `LC_CTYPE` is probably `en_US.utf8`, which is **not** the same as `UTF-8`.

Its a non-IANA character type that supports lowercase letters being before uppercase.

Oddly, [SQLFiddle is also afflicted](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/87012), likewise returning `true` for `'A' > 'a'`

Comment: `en_US.utf8` is the same as `en_US.UTF-8`, right? I verified with another test server running on Linux. It returns `true` too!

Comment: No, utf8 and UTF-8 are different. See https://serverfault.com/questions/616744