# Regular expression to pad zeros

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, natural-sort

I have a series of strings in my table that I want to order.
eg.

```
Chapter 1 
Chapter 2 
Chapter 11 
Chapter 12
```

To order them correctly I would need to pad them with zeros.

```
Chapter 001 
Chapter 002 
Chapter 011 
Chapter 012
```

Maybe I can use **`regexp_replace()`** pad in zeros with the use of a regular expression.

```
  regexp_replace(chapters.name,'(\d+)\D*','0\1') as name
```

This solution does not work. I thought maybe I could figure out the length of the backreference and use that number to pad what I need:

```
  regexp_replace(chapters.name,'(\d+)\D*',lpad('\l',3-length('\1'),'0') as name
```

but a `\1` in `length()` always returns 2, even though I noticed using `\1` in certain postgres function translate `\1` to the actual captured data.

How can I pad zeros using Postgres string functions and Postgres regex?

Answer (score 6):

#### Problems

Your second attempt is victim to two misunderstandings:

- The second parameter of [`lpad()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) and [`rpad()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is the *resulting* total length, not the number of characters to *add*.
- You are confusing the scope of `regexp_replace()` with the scope of `lpad()`. `lpad()` is executed first and `\l` and `\1` have no special meaning to `lpad()`.

#### Solutions

It's a problem of "natural sort". Related answer:

- [Alphanumeric sorting with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417975/alphanumeric-sorting-with-postgresql/11418231#11418231)

As advised over there, the best solution would be to store normalized data to begin with. If the leading 'Chapter ' is actually an immutable string in all values, don't store that at all and just store the number part as `integer`.

If your example values are accurate, we can ignore the leading constant text and just sort by the trailing number. Much quicker than any attempt at reformatting the strings:

```
SELECT *
FROM   chapters
ORDER  BY split_part(name, ' ', 2)::int
```

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

If you really need the zero-padded strings, and the leading text can vary:

```
SELECT split_part(name, ' ', 1) || ' '
    || lpad(split_part(name, ' ', 2), 3,  '0')
FROM   chapters
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4594)

Two function calls plus concatenation, but still faster than `regexp_replace()`. Regular expressions are comparatively expensive.
More examples for `lpad()`:

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164/convert-hex-in-text-representation-to-decimal-number/8335376#8335376)

Comment: This set me on the right path. The data I had wasn't very clean. Some rows had multiple spaces. It also had 3 words. I could have used multiple split_parts, or substring or something else. Anyway I used: `select mapname,
regexp_replace(mapname,'[ ]+[0-9].*',' ') || 
lpad(regexp_replace(mapname,'(.*)[ ]+([0-9].*)','\2'), 3,  '0')
from mapextents
where maptype ~ 'grids'` for this `"Map Index  94";"Map Index 094"
"Map Index 95";"Map Index 095"
"Map Index 100";"Map Index 100"`