# postgres replace calculated value in text

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I have a table column `numbers` containing strings like:

```
1, 2, 2A, 14, 14A, 20
```

Listed in the desired ascending sort order.

How can I formulate an `ORDER BY` clause to achieve this order?

Per default, postgres has to resort to alphabetical order which would be:

```
1, 2, 14, 20, 2A, 14A
```

Can this be done using only the string-manipulation features that come with Postgres? (`replace()`, `regex_replace()` etc?)

My first idea was:

1. cut the letter, if present
2. number * 100
3. add ascii of letter, if present

This would yield the desired result as the mapped values would be:

```
100, 200, 265, 1400, 1465, 2000
```

I could also index this manipulated value to speed up sorting.

**Additional restrictions:**

I cannot use casts to hex numbers, because eg.: `14Z` is valid too.

Ideally, the result is a single expression. I'd need to use this transformation for filtering and sorting like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE transform(numbers) < 15 ORDER BY transform(numbers)
RESULT:

 1, 2, 2A, 14, 14A
```

---

I tried to implement my idea, using what I learned from @klin's answer:

1. Cut the letter and multiply number by 100:

   ```
   substring('12A' from '(\d+).*')::int*100
   ```
2. Cut the numbers and get ASCII of letter:

   ```
   ascii(substring('12A' from '\d+([A-Z])'))
   ```
3. Add the two.

This works fine with `12A`, but does not work with `12`, as the second expression returns `NULL` and not `0` (numeric zero). Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, you would use `WHERE transform(numbers) < 1500` for the desired result in the example since transform() multiplies with 100.

Comment: i would use transform(numbers) < transform('15')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on these **assumptions**:

- Numbers consist of digits and optionally one pending letter and nothing else.
- There is always at least one leading digit.
- All letters are either upper case `[A-Z]` or lower case `[a-z]`, but not mixed.

I would enforce that with a `CHECK` constraint on the table column to be absolutely reliable.

Create a tiny `IMMUTABLE` SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_nr2sort(text)
  RETURNS int AS
$func$
   SELECT CASE WHEN right($1, 1) > '9' COLLATE "C"  -- no collation
               THEN left($1, -1)::int * 100 + ascii(right($1, 1))
               ELSE $1::int * 100 END  -- only digits
$func$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Optimized for performance based on above assumptions. I replaced all regular expressions with the much cheaper [`left()` and `right()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER).

I [disabled collation rules with `COLLATE "C"`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html) for the `CASE` expression (it's cheaper, too) to assure default byte order of ASCII letters. Letters in `[a-zA-Z]` sort above '9' and if that's the case for the last letter, we proceed accordingly.
This way we avoid adding NULL values and don't need to fix with [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

Then your query can be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  f_nr2sort(numbers) < f_nr2sort('15C')
ORDER  BY f_nr2sort(numbers);
```

Since the function is `IMMUTABLE`, you can even create a simple [**functional index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) to support this class of queries:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_foo_id ON tbl (f_nr2sort(numbers));
```

Comment: very clear and straight forward solution, thank you! I added the one i found to my question - in case someone ants to avoid using stored_procedures - it uses coalesce as you mentioned - so you even included the approach i found plus pointed out the immutable keyword for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I am new at PostgreSQL, but I found this very useful post:
[Alphanumeric sorting with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417975/alphanumeric-sorting-with-postgresql)

So what about something like this:

```
select val
from test
order by (substring(val, '^[0-9]+'))::int, substring(val, '[^0-9_].*$') desc
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, his works too, @klins solution looks more clean though. I added a comment to his answer