# Alphanumeric Sorting in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sorting, natural-sort, bytea

I have this table with a `character varying` column in Postgres 9.6:

```
id | column 
------------
1  |IR ABC-1
2  |IR ABC-2
3  |IR ABC-10
```

I see some solutions typecasting the column as `bytea`.

```
select * from table order by column::bytea.
```

But it always results to:

```
id | column 
------------
1  |IR ABC-1
2  |IR ABC-10
3  |IR ABC-2
```

I don't know why '10' always comes before '2'. How do I sort this table, assuming the basis for ordering is the last whole number of the string, regardless of what the character before that number is.

Comment: `10` comes before `2` because `1` comes before `2`

Comment: Have a look at the existing [**\[postgresql\] \[natural-sort\]**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+natural-sort) questions.

Comment: If you want to sort by the name, and then subsort by the number, you'll have to separate the two entities into two columns, and then order by the two columns.

Comment: @evert, i think i can get somewhere with your idea.. but how do i split the column string?

Comment: You forgot to provide column type and Postgres version.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter hi, see my edit.. anyways.. i'm using Postgresql 9.6.0 and column type is character varying.

Comment: If `column` is always in that format you have given in example, you can simply do `split_part(column, '-', 2)::integer` to get integer out of it. Otherwise regexp might be better.

Comment: Why the cast to `bytea`? You want alphanumeric sorting - or at least that's your title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sorting character data types, [**collation** rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html) apply - unless you work with locale "C" which sorts characters by there byte values. Applying collation rules may or may not be desirable. It makes sorting more expensive in any case. If you want to sort without collation rules, don't cast to `bytea`, use `COLLATE "C"` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column COLLATE "C";
```

**However**, this does not yet solve the problem with numbers in the string you mention. Split the string and sort the numeric part as number.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
ORDER  BY split_part(column, '-', 2)::numeric;
```

Or, if all your numbers fit into `bigint` or even `integer`, use that instead (cheaper).

I ignored the leading part because you write:

> ... the basis for ordering is the last whole number of the string, regardless of what the character before that number is.

Related:

- [Alphanumeric sorting with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417975/alphanumeric-sorting-with-postgresql/11418231#11418231)
- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)
- [What is the impact of LC_CTYPE on a PostgreSQL database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/94887/3684)

Typically, it's best to save distinct parts of a string in separate columns as proper respective data types to avoid any such confusion.

And if the leading string is identical for *all* columns, consider just dropping the redundant noise. You can always use a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) to prepend a string for display, or do it on-the-fly, cheaply.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments split and cast the integer part

```
select *
from
    table
    cross join lateral
    regexp_split_to_array(column, '-') r (a)
order by a[1], a[2]::integer
```