# How to sort Alphanumeric using Postgresql (specific data)?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I have trouble in sorting alphanumeric data using postgresql. My data and query are shown as below

```
WITH x(t) AS (
    VALUES
     ('GPS-10')
    ,('GPS-1')
    ,('GPS-2')
    ,('GPS-8B')
    ,('GPS-8A')
    ,('GPS-14')
    ,('SPS-2')
    ,('SPS-14')
    )
SELECT t
FROM   x
ORDER  BY substring(t, '[^0-9-].*$'), (substring(t, '^[0-9]+'))::int
```

It gave me the this wrong result (GPS-2 comes after GPS-10 and GPS-14 so does the SPS data)

```
"GPS-1"
"GPS-10"
"GPS-14"
"GPS-2"
"GPS-8A"
"GPS-8B"
"SPS-14"
"SPS-2"
```

My expected result is

```
"GPS-1"
"GPS-2"
"GPS-8A"
"GPS-8B"
"GPS-10"
"GPS-14"
"SPS-2"
"SPS-14"
```

I have tried all solutions described in [Alphanumeric sorting with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417975/alphanumeric-sorting-with-postgresql/11418231) and [Alphanumeric sorting with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417975/alphanumeric-sorting-with-postgresql/11418231) and didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do that, some thing like this:

```
   WITH x(t) AS (
    VALUES
     ('GPS-10')
    ,('GPS-1')
    ,('GPS-2')
    ,('GPS-8B')
    ,('GPS-8A')
    ,('GPS-14')
    ,('SPS-2')
    ,('SPS-14')
    )
SELECT t
FROM   x
ORDER  BY substring(t, 1,3), (substring(substring(t, 5, length(t)), '^[0-9]+'))::int
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add a few constraints. I edited my post and added new data. The above code will fail to process the `GPS-8A` and `GPS-8B`. Can you help me?

Comment: Thank you! I see you add substring inside a substring