# Get element of character varying type by index or convert it to array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have some sql function that returns `character varying` type. The output is something like this:
'TTFFFFNN'. I need to get this characters by index. How to convert character varying to array?

Comment: `substring(some_column, index, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`string_to_array()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html) with NULL as delimiter (pg **9.1+**):

```
SELECT string_to_array('TTFFFFNN'::text, NULL) AS arr;
```

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html)

> In `string_to_array`, if the delimiter parameter is NULL, each character
>   in the input string will become a separate element in the resulting array.

In older versions (pg 9.0-), the call with NULL returned NULL. ([Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/d41d8/330))

To get the 2nd position (example):

```
SELECT (string_to_array('TTFFFFNN'::text, NULL))[2] AS item2;
```

#### Alternatives

For **single characters** I would use `substring()` directly, like [@a_horse commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570174/get-element-of-character-varying-type-by-index-or-convert-it-to-array/27570247?noredirect=1#comment43565735_27570174):

```
SELECT substring('TTFFFFNN'::text, 2, 1) AS item2;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4167) showing both.

For strings **with actual delimiters**, I suggest `split_part()`:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

Only use `regexp_split_to_array()` if you must. Regular expression processing is more expensive.

Comment: but indexing returns no result:select (string_to_array('TTFFFFNN'::text, NULL))[2]

Comment: @Andrew: Sure it does. I tested, it works. Added example above.

Comment: that's strange. It returns nothing anyway.

Comment: @Andrew: I suspect you are using an old version. I seem to remember different behavior with NULL in old versions. That's why you should *always* state the version of your software in the question ...

Comment: the same question: do you know, why I can't call function in substing? select substing("FUNCGETRIGHTS"(0,89), 1, 1); My functions returns the same: 'TTFFFFNN'; Error tells that there is no fuction matches the given name and argument types and points at substring function;

Comment: @Andrew: "substing"? substring.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solutions outlined by Erwin and a horse, you can use `regexp_split_to_array()` with an empty regexp instead:

```
select regexp_split_to_array('TTFFFFNN'::text, '');
```

With an index, that becomes:

```
select (regexp_split_to_array('TTFFFFNN'::text, ''))[2];
```