# Seperate first and last names from single column

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring, delimiter

I have a `person` table where the `name` column contains names, some in the format "first last" and some in the format "first".

My query

```
SELECT name,
SUBSTRING(name FROM 1 FOR POSITION(' ' IN name) ) AS first_name
FROM person
```

creates a new row of first names, but it doesn't work for the names which only have a first name and no blank space at all.

I know I need a `CASE` statement with something like `0 = (' ', name)` but I keep running into syntax errors and would appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [**`split_part()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT split_part(name, ' ', 1) AS first_name
     , split_part(name, ' ', 2) AS last_name
FROM person;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/080a8/2)

Related:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
select 
 substring(name from '^([\w\-]+)') first_name,
 substring(name from '\s(\w+)$') last_name
from person
```

2.

```
select (regexp_split_to_array(name, ' '))[1] first_name
     , (regexp_split_to_array(name, ' '))[2] last_name
from person
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Erwin and Danstopka have the best answer in their own style. I have used their approach to extend to my use case where we wanted middle name only if it exists.

--Example

```
WITH tablename( name )      AS 
     ( 
            SELECT 'Barn KE Roman' 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT 'Utry Rita' 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT 'Jam Ilya Dimo' 
     ) 
SELECT (Regexp_split_to_array(NAME, ' '))[1] first_name , ( 
       CASE 
              WHEN array_length(regexp_split_to_array(NAME, ' '),1) > 2 THEN (regexp_split_to_array(NAME, ' '))[2] 
       END ) middle_name , ( 
       CASE 
              WHEN array_length(regexp_split_to_array(NAME, ' '),1) > 2 THEN (regexp_split_to_array(NAME, ' '))[3] 
              ELSE (regexp_split_to_array(NAME, ' '))[2] 
       END ) last_name 
FROM   tablename
```

Nothing special, I take the length of each array and check if the it has more than 3 words and then decide the middle and last name accordingly.