# PostgreSQL 9.3: Split given string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to split the given comma separated string into columns.

I have a table with two columns:

**Example**:

```
create table t3
(
    cola varchar,
    colb varchar
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
insert into t3 values('AD1','2000-01-01to2000-02-01'),
                     ('AD2','2000-03-01to2000-04-01'),
                     ('AD3','2000-05-01to2000-06-01');
```

Now I want prepare two comma separated strings from the given above records to like this:

```
str1 varchar = 'AD1,AD2,AD3';

str2 varchar = '2000-01-01to2000-02-01,2000-03-01to2000-04-01,2000-05-01to2000-06-01';
```

Now I want to store the comma separated string and in second string there is **to** for separation into two dates, want 
to store into the temp table.

Like this:

**Expected Output**:

```
c1       c2              c3
--------------------------------- 
AD1  2000-01-01       2000-02-01
AD2  2000-03-01       2000-04-01
AD3  2000-05-01       2000-06-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the output you want using:

```
select cola as col1,
       cast(left(colb, 10) as date) as col2,
       cast(right(colb, 10) as date) as col2
from t3;
```

I have no idea why you would want to create intermediate comma-separated strings, which are not needed for the logic.

Comment: Wow! That's really great. And  yes you are right, I don't need to create intermediate comma-separated strings. That's my bad logic.

Answer (score 1):

[**`split_part()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) is typically simplest and fastest for this purpose:

```
SELECT cola AS c1
     , split_part(colb, 'to', 1)::date AS c2
     , split_part(colb, 'to', 2)::date AS c3
FROM   t3;
```

This is more robust and even works if one or both dates in the string vary in length. The cast requires a valid date string either way.
Related:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)