# Get substring from a column with delimiter and varying number of elements

Tags: postgresql, split, substring, pattern-matching

A column in my table in Postgres has `varchar` values in the format: `'str1/str2'` or `'str1/str2/str3'` where `str` represents any string.

I want to write a select query which will return me `str2`. I surfed but couldn't find any proper function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**`split_part()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT split_part(col, '/', 2) AS result
FROM tbl;
```

As [Victoria pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741084/get-substring-from-a-column-with-delimiter-and-varying-number-of-elements/32741432#comment86790966_32741432), the index is 1-based,

Obviously, the delimiter needs to be unambiguous. It (`/` in your example) cannot cannot be part of a substring. (Unless that's to the right of what you extract, which is ignored anyway.)

Related:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

Comment: Note: not 0-indexed: 1 = first element in the delimited field.