# Combine elements of array into different array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

I need to split text elements in an array and combine the elements (array_agg) by index into different rows

E.g., input is

```
'{cat$ball$x... , dog$bat$y...}'::text[]
```

I need to split each element by '$' and the desired output is:

```
{cat,dog} - row 1
{ball,bat} - row 2
{x,y} - row 3
...
```

Sorry for not being clear the first time. I have edited my question. I tried similar options but unable to figure out how to get it with multiple text elements separated with '$' sysmbol

Comment: What do you mean by list? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Exactly two parts per array element (original question)

Use `unnest()`, `split_part()` and `array_agg()`:

```
SELECT array_agg(split_part(t, '$', 1)) AS col1
     , array_agg(split_part(t, '$', 2)) AS col2
FROM   unnest('{cat$ball, dog$bat}'::text[]) t;
```

Related:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

#### General solution (updated question)

For *any* number of arrays with *any* number of elements containing *any* number of parts.

Demo for a table `tbl`:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (tbl_id int PRIMARY KEY, arr text[]);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1, '{cat1$ball1, dog2$bat2}')  -- 2 parts per array element, 2 elements
, (2, '{cat$ball$x, dog$bat$y}')  -- 3 parts ...
, (3, '{a1$b1$c1$d1, a2$b2$c2$d2, a3$b3$c3$d3}');  -- 4 parts, 3 elements
```

Query:

```
SELECT tbl_id, idx, array_agg(elem ORDER BY ord) AS pivoted_array
FROM   tbl t
     , unnest(t.arr) WITH ORDINALITY a1(string, ord)
     , unnest(string_to_array(a1.string, '$')) WITH ORDINALITY a2(elem, idx)
GROUP  BY tbl_id, idx
ORDER  BY tbl_id, idx;
```

We are looking at two (nested) `LATERAL` joins here. `LATERAL` requires Postgres 9.3. Details:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

`WITH ORDINALITY` for the the first `unnest()` is up for debate. A simpler query *normally works*, too. It's just not guaranteed to work according to SQL standards:

```
SELECT tbl_id, idx, array_agg(elem) AS pivoted_array
FROM   tbl t
     , unnest(t.arr) string
     , unnest(string_to_array(string, '$')) WITH ORDINALITY a2(elem, idx)
GROUP  BY tbl_id, idx
ORDER  BY tbl_id, idx;
```

Details:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

`WITH ORDINALITY` requires Postgres 9.4 or later. The same back-patched to Postgres 9.3:

```
SELECT tbl_id, idx, array_agg(arr2[idx]) AS pivoted_array
FROM   tbl t
     , LATERAL (
         SELECT string_to_array(string, '$') AS arr2  -- convert string to array
         FROM   unnest(t.arr) string  -- unnest org. array
         ) x
     , generate_subscripts(arr2, 1) AS idx  -- unnest 2nd array with ord. numbers
GROUP  BY tbl_id, idx
ORDER  BY tbl_id, idx;
```

Each query returns:

```
 tbl_id | idx | pivoted_array
--------+-----+---------------
      1 |   1 | {cat,dog}
      1 |   2 | {bat,ball}
      1 |   3 | {y,x}
      2 |   1 | {cat2,dog2}
      2 |   2 | {ball2,bat2}
      3 |   1 | {a3,a1,a2}
      3 |   2 | {b1,b2,b3}
      3 |   3 | {c2,c1,c3}
      3 |   4 | {d2,d3,d1}
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ae020/2) (still stuck on pg 9.3).

The ***only requirement*** for these queries is that the **number of parts** in elements of the same array is constant. We could even make it work for a varying number of parts using `crosstab()` with two parameters to fill in NULL values for missing parts, but that's beyond the scope of this question:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!. Sorry for not being clear the first time. I tried similar things and now trying to solve when there are varying number of strings separated with '$' sign. Also, the number of text separated by '$' in each array element will always be the same

Comment: Thank you!! (For the solution and the references). Good Learning!!

Answer (score 0):

A bit messy but you could unnest the array, use regex to separate the text and then aggregate back up again:

```
with a as (select unnest('{cat$ball, dog$bat}'::_text) some_text),
b as (select regexp_matches(a.some_text, '(^[a-z]*)\$([a-z]*$)') animal_object from a)
select array_agg(animal_object[1]) animal, array_agg(animal_object[2]) a_object
from b
```

If you're processing multiple records at once you may want to use something like a row number before the unnest so that you have a group by to aggregate back to an array in your final select statement.