# PostgreSQL: How to get the first letter of each words and add period [.] after?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get the first letter word and put add period after it.

Here is my sample data of a middlename:

```
Dela Torre
Delacruz
De Los Santos
```

I need to have result of:

```
D.T.
D.
D.L.S
```

I do try a sample query like this but only the first letter I could get.

```
cast(a.first_name  ||' ' ||  
SUBSTRING (a.middle_name, 1,1) ||'. '|| 
a.last_name   as text) as name
```

RESULT: first_name **D.** last_name

How can I able to do that?

Comment: You need to split middle name into array (like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8585472/1300049) and then get the first letter of each element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it

```sql
SELECT id, first_name || ' ' || string_agg(left(m, 1) || '.', '') || ' ' || last_name AS name
  FROM (
    SELECT id, first_name, unnest(string_to_array(middle_name, ' ')) m, last_name
      FROM table1
  ) q
 GROUP BY id, first_name, last_name
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8a8b8/3)

Answer (score 3):

If your strings are nicely formatted starting with a capital letter and lower-case letters otherwise, you can use a regular expression to do this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(middle_name, '([a-z ])+', '.', 'g');
```

The regular expression "says": take one or more subsequent lowercase letters or spaces and replace it with a single dot `.`. The `'g'` (global) modifier repeats this for all occurrences.

In combination with `first_name` and `last_name`:

```
SELECT concat_ws(' ', first_name, 
                 regexp_replace(middle_name, '([a-z ])+', '.', 'g'),
                 last_name
                ) AS name
FROM my_table;
```

If - as seems to be the case - the name can be any combination of upper-case and lower-case letters then you must split the name into an array, take the first letter and re-assemble it:

```
SELECT concat_ws(' ', first_name, middle, last_name) AS name
FROM (
    SELECT first_name, string_agg(left(middle, 1), '.') AS middle, last_name
    FROM my_table, unnest(string_to_array(middle_name, ' ')) m(middle)
    GROUP BY first_name, last_name) sub;
```

This assumes that there are no duplicate `(first_name, last_name)` pairs. If so, you should include a primary key or some other unique row identifier.

Comment: I try it but the result became: first_name DELA.CRUZ last_name, it shoud be first_name D.L. last_name

Comment: Apparently your middle names are capitalized, unlike what you posted in your question. See updated answer.