# How to get multiple comma-separated values as individual columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, pivot, delimiter

I have a table with data like this:

```
select * from data

id |  col1 |  col2 |  col3
---+-------+-------+-------
 1 | 1,2,3 | 4,5,6 | 7,8,9
```

I want to get the data like this:

```
id | name | dd | fn | suf
---+------+----+----+-----
1  | col1 |  1 |  2 |  3
1  | col2 |  4 |  5 |  6
1  | col3 |  7 |  8 |  9
```

Currently, I use [split_part()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) in a query like this:

```
SELECT * from(
select id,
       'col1' as name,
       NULLIF(split_part(col1, ',', 1), '') AS dd, 
       NULLIF(split_part(col1, ',', 2), '') AS fn, 
       NULLIF(split_part(col1, ',', 3), '') AS suf
       from data

       UNION 
       select id,
       'col2' as name,
       NULLIF(split_part(col2, ',', 1), '') AS dd, 
       NULLIF(split_part(col2, ',', 2), '') AS fn, 
       NULLIF(split_part(col2, ',', 3), '') AS suf
       from data
        UNION 
       select id,
       'col3' as name,
       NULLIF(split_part(col3, ',', 1), '') AS dd, 
       NULLIF(split_part(col3, ',', 2), '') AS fn, 
       NULLIF(split_part(col3, ',', 3), '') AS suf
       from data
);
```

Is there a more elegant way? **I have 20 columns**.

Comment: You should use the Postgres function `split_part()`.

Comment: see my requirement.

Comment: Your table definition and Postgres version would help. Data type of `col1`, `col2`, `col3` is `text`? or `int[]`? Elements are integer values? A maximum of 3 elements? Can there be 0 elements (empty string / array)? Desired result for that? Missing elements shall produce a NULL value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int, col1 text, col2 text, col3 text);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1 ,'1,2,3', '4,5,6', '7,8,9');
```

A `VALUES` expression in a `LATERAL` subquery should be an elegant solution.
Then just use `split_part()`. Add `NULLIF()` only if there can be actual empty strings in the source ...

```
SELECT id, x.name
     , split_part(x.col, ',', 1) AS dd
     , split_part(x.col, ',', 2) AS fn
     , split_part(x.col, ',', 3) AS suf
FROM   tbl t, LATERAL (
   VALUES (text 'col1', t.col1)
        , (     'col2', t.col2)
        , (     'col3', t.col3)
        -- ... many more?
   ) x(name, col);
```

Works in PostgreSQL 9.3 or later.
[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/80321/4)

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102677/select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/102743#102743)
- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

Comment: where name column ?

Comment: @PSM: I added the column `name`.

Comment: Thanks.You saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the `union all` first and the `split_part()` second:

```
select id, name,
       coalesce(split_part(col, ',', 1), '') as dd,
       coalesce(split_part(col, ',', 2), '') as fn,
       coalesce(split_part(col, ',', 3), '') as suf
from ((select id, 'col1' as name, col1 as col from data
      ) union all
      (select id, 'col2' as name, col2 as col from data
      ) union all
      (select id, 'col3' as name, col3 as col from data
      )
     ) t;
```