# Extract Value from a string PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, extract

Simple Question

I have the following type of results in a string field

```
'Number=123456'
'Number=1234567'
'Number=12345678'
```

How do I extract the value from the string with regard that the value can change between 5-8 figures

So far I did this but I doubt that fits my requirement

```
SELECT substring('Size' from 8 for ....
```

If I can tell it to start from the = sign till the end that would help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely simplest solution is to trim 7 leading characters with [`right()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
right(str, -7)
```

Demo:

```sql
SELECT str, right(str, -7)
FROM (
   VALUES ('Number=123456')
        , ('Number=1234567')
        , ('Number=12345678')
   ) t(str);

       str       |  right
-----------------+----------
 Number=123456   | 123456
 Number=1234567  | 1234567
 Number=12345678 | 12345678
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT col, REPLACE(col, 'Number=', '')
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=321f39782e139092c321411dc0f749b2)**

Answer (score 2):

Based on this question:
[Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns)

You could probably do the following:

```
SELECT *, split_part(col, '=', 2)
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `regexp_matches` :

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'Number=123456'   union all 
 select 'Number=1234567'  union all
 select 'Number=12345678' union all
 select 'Number=12345678x9' 
)
select t.str  as "String", 
       regexp_matches(t.str, '=([A-Za-z0-9]+)', 'g')  as "Number"
  from t;

String            Number
--------------    ---------
Number=123456     123456
Number=1234567    1234567
Number=12345678   12345678
Number=12345678x9 12345678x9 
--> the last line shows only we look chars after equal sign even if non-digit
```

[***Rextester Demo***](http://rextester.com/UAB57446)