# SQL join table on partial string

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-parsing

I have two tables in a Postgres database:

Table A:

```
**Middle_name**
John
Joe
Fred
Jim Bob
Paul-John
```

Table B:

```
**Full_name**
Fred, Joe, Bobda
Jason, Fred, Anderson
Tom, John, Jefferson
Jackson, Jim Bob, Sager
Michael, Paul-John, Jensen
```

Sometimes the middle name is hyphenated or has a space between it. But there is never a comma in the middle name. If it is hyphenated or two middle names, the entries will still be the same in both Table A and Table B.

I want to join the tables on `Middle_name` and `Full_name`. The difficult part is that the join has to check only the values between the commas in `Full_name`. Otherwise it might match the first name accidentally.

I've been using the query below but I just realized that there is nothing stopping it from matching the middle name to a first name accidentally.

```
SELECT Full_name, Middle_name
FROM B
JOIN A
ON POSITION(Middle_name IN Full_name)>0
```

I'm wondering how I can refactor this query to match only the middle name (assuming they all appear in the same format).

Comment: I don't have a middle name. Just sayin ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  `split_part`(`'Fred, Joe, Bobda', ',', 2)` which returns the middle name `joe`

```
SELECT Full_name, Middle_name
FROM B
JOIN A
ON split_part(B.Full_name, ',', 2)=A.Middle_name
```

[demo for returning middle name](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a1994b824a1b7bfc7582797b7695c6b4)

Answer (score 0):

If there is *always* exactly one space after the comma, and *everybody* has a middle name like your sample data suggests, the space can just be part of the delimiter in [split_part()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT full_name, middle_name
FROM   A
JOIN   B ON split_part(B.full_name, ', ', 2) = A.middle_name;
```

Related:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)