# Casting from postgres array comma delimited values to rows and columns

Tags: c#, sql, .net, postgresql

i have arrived at the following result set in postgres and is a bit stuck. the values came from an uploaded excel file so what i have here is a column of comma delimited values with the first row as the headers and all following as values

```
|   values     |
|col1,col2,col3|
|val1,val2,val3|
|val1,val2,val3|
```

my question is how can i arrive to my desired output described below

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| val1 | val2 | val3 |
| cal1 | val2 | val3 |
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns)

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is `split_part()`:

```
select split_part(col, ',', 1) as col1,
       split_part(col, ',', 2) as col2,
       split_part(col, ',', 3) as col3
from t;
```

However, this does not allow you to reassign the column names.  That is going to be quite tricky.  I would recommend that you just hard-code the values and remove the row that looks like it has the column names.

Answer (score -1):

This is just a basic draft on the how part.

```
GetFirstRow()
.SplitByNewLine()
.SplitByComma()
.SortByIndexIntoTheeseLists(hereAreTheLists)
....
.Profit();
```

Hope it helps you out.

Comment: I recommand you delete it, this is not an answer, because it's not answered this question. Otherwise you may will got some downvote.

Comment: Das my Squirrel!
Although I would suggest changing the `....` to `????` would be good also.