# Querying on items returned by STRING_TO_ARRAY

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, split

In a nutshell, I am trying to return all distinct (3rd level) entries in a path; provided the entry has 3 slashes. That statement alone makes me think I've over-complicated this, but I can't see a way around the extra ceremony here.

**Given "character" table:**

```
id | role    | path
===================
0  | hero    | one/two/luke
1  | hero    | one/two/wicket/chak
2  | hero    | one/two/wicket/den/aqi/bet
3  | grifter | one/two/han/frozen
4  | hero    | one/two/leia/cgi
5  | hero    | one/two/c3po/mem_wipe
```

**Expected:**

wicket, leia, c3po

**Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT (STRING_TO_ARRAY(c.path,'/'))[3] 
FROM character c 
WHERE c.role='hero' 
AND c.path IN 
(SELECT path FROM character c WHERE role='hero' AND c.path like '%/%/[INPUT]/%');
```

I am stuck trying to figure out how to formulate this query. If I replace "[INPUT]" with "wicket", I get the expected "wicket" returned, but I want wicket, leia and c3po (and anything else) to be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`split_part()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html). See:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT split_part(path, '/', 3)
FROM   character
WHERE  role = 'hero'
AND    path LIKE '%/%/%/%';
```

This `LIKE` pattern demands at least 3 slashes. But because`%` stands for *anything* in a `LIKE` pattern, there can be *nothing* left and right of slashes, or any number of additional slashes, too.

For *exactly* 3 slashes, and more than an empty string left and right of each slash, I'd use a regular expression:

```sql
...
AND    path ~ '^[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+$';
```

Ingredients of the regexp pattern:

`^` ... start of string
`[^/]` ... character class with any character except the slash
`+` ... one or more of that atom
`/` ... literal slash
...
`$` ... end of string

Or else define your *exact* filter.