# How to get the nth match from regexp_matches() as plain text

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have this code:

```
with demo as (
select 'WWW.HELLO.COM' web
union all
select 'hi.co.uk' web)
select regexp_matches(replace(lower(web),'www.',''),'([^\.]*)') from demo
```

And the table I get is:

```
regexp_matches
{hello}
{hi}
```

What I would like to do is:

```
with demo as (
select 'WWW.HELLO.COM' web
union all
select 'hi.co.uk' web)
select regexp_matches(replace(lower(web),'www.',''),'([^\.]*)')[1] from demo
```

Or even the big query version:

```
with demo as (
select 'WWW.HELLO.COM' web
union all
select 'hi.co.uk' web)
select regexp_matches(replace(lower(web),'www.',''),'([^\.]*)')[offset(1)] from demo
```

But neither works.  Is this possible?  If it isn't clear, the result I would like is:

```
match
hello
hi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  Doesn't this do what you want?

```
with demo as (
      select 'WWW.HELLO.COM' web
      union all
      select 'hi.co.uk' web
     )
select (regexp_matches(replace(lower(web), 'www.',''), '([^\.]*)'))[1]
from demo
```

This is basically your query with extra parentheses so it does not generate a syntax error.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c5e658b02743a0a1151ab90c5103b2ed) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that it returns what you want.

Comment: This is it, of course the other solution worked also.  Why the extra parenthesis?  I'm a little confused

Comment: @HenriettaMartingale . . . I assume you mean the parentheses around `regexp_matches()`.  That is so the expression can use `[]` for addressing an array element.  I think of it as a quirk of Postgres syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`split_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) instead. Simpler, faster. To get the first word, before the first separator `.`:

```sql
WITH demo(web) AS (
   VALUES
      ('WWW.HELLO.COM')
    , ('hi.co.uk')
   )
SELECT split_part(replace(lower(web), 'www.', ''), '.', 1)
FROM   demo;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=44796b78a3a249008a5ed8609d9afb4a)*

See:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

[`regexp_matches()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) returns `setof text[]`, i.e. 0-n rows of text arrays. (Because each regular expression can result in a set of multiple matching strings.)

In Postgres 10 or later, there is also the simpler variant [`regexp_match()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) that only returns the first match, i.e. `text[]`. Either way, the surrounding curly braces in your result are the text representation of the *array* literal.

You can take the first row and unnest the first element of the array, but since you neither want the set nor the array to begin with, use `split_part()` instead. Simpler, faster, and less versatile. But good enough for the purpose. And it returns exactly what you want to begin with: `text`.