# How to get latest version of a product from a jsonb array?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, json-path-expression

Using PostgreSQL 12.7, I'd like to get the latest version of a product (maximum value) from a nested JSON array. Here is a sample value from column `fields` for `product` 'AAA':

```
 "customfield_01":[
      {
         "id":1303,
         "name":"AAA - 1.82.0",
         "state":"closed",
         "boardId":137,
         "endDate":"2021-10-15T10:00:00.000Z",
         "startDate":"2021-10-04T01:00:01.495Z",
         "completeDate":"2021-10-18T03:02:55.824Z"
      },
      {
         "id":1304,
         "name":"AAA - 1.83.0",
         "state":"active",
         "boardId":137,
         "endDate":"2021-10-29T10:00:00.000Z",
         "startDate":"2021-10-18T01:00:24.324Z"
      }
   ],
```

I tried:

```
SELECT product, jsonb_path_query_array(fields, '$.customfield_01.version') AS version
FROM product.issues;
```

Here is the output:

```
| product | version                                       |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| CCC     |[]                                             |
| AAA     |["AAA - 1.83.0", "AAA - 1.82.0"]               |
| BBB     |["BBB - 1.83.0", "BBB - 1.82.0", "BBB - 1.84.0]|
| BBB     |["BBB - 1.83.0"]                               |
| BBB     |["BBB - 1.84.0", "BBB - 1.83.0"]               |
```

Expected is:

```
| product | version                                       |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| AAA     |["AAA - 1.83.0"                                |
| BBB     |["BBB - 1.84.0]                                |
| BBB     |["BBB - 1.83.0"]                               |
| BBB     |["BBB - 1.84.0"]                               |
```

Tried unnest/Array but it threw an error:

```
SELECT max(version)
FROM  (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY [jsonb_path_query_array(fields,'$.customfield_01.version')]) AS version FROM product.issues ) AS version;
```

Did using -1, but it will only get the rightmost of the data.

```
jsonb_path_query_array(fields, '$.customfield_01.version') ->> -1
```

Very new with Postgres & json. Did try to read documentation and google, however multiple attempts failed.

Comment: Be so kind as to also provide your *input* value, and always your version of Postgres.

Comment: Thanks. Just updated the post with the input value.

Comment: `Select version();`?

Comment: was figuring how to get it, thanks! here is the version
PostgreSQL 12.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `product` is the primary key column of your table.

You *can* use a [SQL/JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) expression:

```sql
SELECT product, max(version) AS latest_version
FROM   product.issues;
     , jsonb_array_elements_text(jsonb_path_query_array(fields, '$.customfield_01.name')) AS version 
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

But simple `jsonb` operators achieve the same:

```sql
SELECT product, max(version ->> 'name') AS latest_version
FROM   product.issues
     , jsonb_array_elements(fields -> 'customfield_01') AS version
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Use `jsonb_array_elements()` or `jsonb_array_elements_text()` to unnest a **`jsonb` array**. See:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

[`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) (like you tried) can be used to unnest a **Postgres array**.

Of course, `max()` only works while the "latest version" sorts alphabetically last. Else, **extract the version part and process all parts as numbers**. Like:

```sql
SELECT i.product, v.*
FROM   issues i
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT version ->> 'name' AS version, string_to_array(split_part(version ->> 'name', ' - ', 2), '.')::int[] AS numeric_order
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(i.fields -> 'customfield_01') AS version
   ORDER  BY 2 DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) v ON true;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=92e4bbcc1be86a01e6c5d2637532193a)*

See:

- [How to ORDER BY typical software release versions like X.Y.Z?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74298/3684)
- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

Comment: Apology for the confusion. Let me rephrase. actually I'd like to get the latest version of the product. 
I'm encountering this error while trying 
ERROR:  cannot extract elements from a scalar