# Split a string column to new columns postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, metabase

I have a column which can contain over 20 different values and they are seprated by semicolon.
for example : `A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;....`, I need to split all the values in new columns.
I tried to split it with `SPLIT_PART()`, but it seems i need to sepcify which position do i want from the string. But in my case, there are too many values and it's not very effcient to do like this.

I wonder if there's anyway that I can split them by ; and all value will be saved in a new column?

Comment: I suggest just reloading your table using Postgres' CSV loading tool.  Then the data will arrive in a table with the columns you expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns)

Comment: If you want multiple columns there is no way around writing one expression for each column you want in the output.

Comment: okya thanks you for the input! I thought there could be an easy way to do that :( , thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into an array and select array elements. A CTE stands for the table.
Here is an illustration for 10 columns. Still somewhat verbose but of a regular nature.

```sql
with the_table(s) as 
(
 values
 ('A01;B01;C01;D01;E01;F01;G01;H01;I01;J01'),
 ('A02;B02;C02;D02;E02;F02;G02;H02;I02;J02'),
 ('A03;B03;C03;D03;E03;F03;G03;H03;I03;J03')
),
arr(a) as 
(
 select string_to_array(s,';') from the_table
)
select 
  a[1] c1,a[2] c2,a[3] c3,a[4] c4,a[5]  c5,
  a[6] c6,a[7] c7,a[8] c8,a[9] c9,a[10] c10 -- ...
from arr;
```

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 | c8 | c9 | c10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | B01 | C01 | D01 | E01 | F01 | G01 | H01 | I01 | J01 |
| A02 | B02 | C02 | D02 | E02 | F02 | G02 | H02 | I02 | J02 |
| A03 | B03 | C03 | D03 | E03 | F03 | G03 | H03 | I03 | J03 |

Comment: so i have to write the 1 to 10 index to get the value? I thought therei will be a more effcient way. But thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you do not have to use offsets and lengths. Just a regular sequence of numbers. And if the offsets/lengths change from record to record it will still work correctly.