# Extract type and phone number from string

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, split

I have a varchar which can have these values:

```
"Office: (415) 438-4437"
"Office: (602) 740-6409 Fred Cohen"
"Mobile: (707) 888-572"
"Phone: (707) 472-0982"
```

I need to separate these values as phone_type and phone columns.

Should look like these

| phone type | phone |
| --- | --- |
| Office | (415) 438-4437 |
| Office | (602) 740-6409 |
| Mobile | (707) 888-572 |
| Phone | (707) 472-0982 |

Here my code

```
select phone from core.person;
```

I can have more data after the phone number, but Just need to pick the first word of the string which is the phone_type and the phone which is `(###) ###-####`, how to do that?

Comment: I took the liberty to fix your results to match your input. Undo if I got that wrong.

Comment: *Here my code*: What code? The single bit of SQL you posted makes no effort to do anything that your question asks about doing. What effort have you made to actually solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be as simple as:

```sql
SELECT split_part(phone, ': ', 1)                  AS phone_type
     , rtrim(substring(phone, '\([\d\) -]+'))      AS phone
     , substring(phone, '\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{3,4}') AS phone_strict
FROM   core.person;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f7ece3d5726706e89a6fce4d79e45e53)*

The second variant is stricter. (But still not strictly `(###) ###-####` like you wrote, which seems wrong about the trailing 4 digits.)

We could use a regular expression for the `phone_type`, too, but `split_part()` is simpler and faster.

About `split_part()`:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

About `substring()` and [regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

- [Postgres - Return default value if regex match fails](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210137/3684)

Answer (score 0):

May be try REGEXP_SUBSTR like the following:

```
--splitting the text with delimiter as ':'
--removing " to clean the remaining text
    Select replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR('"Office: (415) 438-4437"', '[^:]+', 1, 1), '"') as Phone_Type,
    replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR('"Office: (415) 438-4437"', '[^:]+', 1,2), '"') as Phone  from Dual;
```