# Insert Substrings in Each Row on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, substring

```
create table phone_log(phone_number CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                      area_code CHAR(10));

INSERT INTO phone_log(phone_number) 
     VALUES ('310-430-9201');
    
INSERT INTO phone_log(phone_number)
    VALUES ('917-829-2876');
    
INSERT INTO phone_log(phone_number)
    VALUES ('424-917-1055')
```

[image]

How do I insert the area code of each phone number using the **SUBSTRING FUNCTION** for each row?

I want the result to be like below:

[image]

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using the substring function update in existing row is done. try the below query: -

```
UPDATE phone_log
SET area_code = SUBSTRING(phone_number, 1, 3)
WHERE area_code IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `area_code` can vary in length (which is usually the case), I suggest `split_part()`:

```
INSERT INTO phone_log(phone_number, area_code)
SELECT nr, split_part(nr, '-', 1)
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('310-430-9201')
   , ('917-829-2876')
   , ('424-917-1055')
   ) input(nr);
```

See:

- [Split comma separated column data into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584967/split-comma-separated-column-data-into-additional-columns/8612456#8612456)

If you must store the functionally dependent value for `area_code` redundantly (which I would try to avoid), consider a **generated column**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE phone_log2 (
  phone_log_id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, phone_number text NOT NULL
, area_code    text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (split_part(phone_number, '-', 1)) STORED
);
```

Then your original simple `INSERT` commands just work.

See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

Either way, you do **not** want to use `char(n)`, which is short for `character(n)`. Use `text` or `varchar(n)` instead. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KEtfxvXq)